# command prompt opens without me opening it

Tags: visual-studio-code, command

My laptop always pops up the command prompt repeatedly while I am working without me running it, and this always happens anytime I am using vs code.
I already tried uninstalling and reinstalling vs code but the problem still keeps repeating itself

Comment: Welcome! Please copy and paste the output of the `Help: About` command (run in [the command palette](//code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/userinterface#_command-palette)) **into your question post**. Does this happen when you reload VS Code with extensions disabled (use the `Developer: Reload With Extensions Disabled` command in the command palette)? If not, then do an [extension bisect](//code.visualstudio.com/blogs/2021/02/16/extension-bisect) to figure out what extension is causing it.

Comment: what do you see in the command prompt window? does it happen when you perform a specific action? what do you see about the process in the task manager?